# what's the name for this ethernet cable with 5 rectangles based on this logo?

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, port

Regular ethernet cable can't fit on my laptop, i need to buy ethernet cable for this port/slot.
what's the name for this port?

[image: kk]

Answer (score 2):

It takes a standard Ethernet cable - the bottom half of the port is supposed to open up to accept a regular Ethernet cable. You just need to carefully pull down the 'jaw' and put the cable in 'upside down' from the usual orientation, with the clip facing the bottom/gap of the port.

Comment: no it does not fit there..

Comment: oh eyes it works!!!! thx u